Ghostscript converting PDF to Text file but output unreadable
I was trying to convert a 7 page pdf document which is in Urdu/Arabic language. Ghostscript succeded in converting the pdf to txt but the resulting text file is unreadable with junk characters.
Here is the code which I executed:
c:\gs\gswin64c.exe -sDEVICE=txtwrite -o output.txt input.pdf
Here is the partial output: Å+*6,~óäâiL!‚ggpÆð+Zg**c*ŠXåtØ»™V*¹„Ð‚ÃP*6,Xå ìgõåÃy!*izŠgZ6,Z# ¸Ð~Vzg»ðyZ}gøP*6,X‰Cƒù¿áV*¹
I am using using Ghostscript version 10.031.
What am I missing ?

@KJHow do I do Unicode Mapping in Ghostscript?

Here are the links of the two files which needs to be converted to text.
https://www.mediafire.com/file/j650t4l68b9hmo1/input.pdf/file
https://www.mediafire.com/file/qazm3ae7wqvv905/inputn.pdf/file

@KJThank you for the effort. It seems lot of work. It would be much easier for a layman like me to type it from the scratch. I know there are lots of pages but my knowledge of above tools are nil. Can Tesseract help me if I train the data ?
